# Which statement is more efficient?

Tags: c#, compare

```
bankOptionEntity.AutoCompleteForForm = 
    (string.Compare(dr["Value"].ToString().Trim(), "Y", true) == 0);
```

OR

```
bankOptionEntity.AutoCompleteForForm =
    dr["Value"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("Y");
```

Comment: What are the results when you test them?

Comment: why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: You're gonna have to explain why you need this code to be the most efficient possible. The two lines should run roughly the same afaik

Comment: Simply use `dr["Value"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper() == "Y"`

Comment: I'll give it a shot Msonic.  Reading a value the value can be Yes,No or "".  While looking at severl places in an existing application I noticed two different developers were coding in two seperate styles. I wasn't looking to get downgraded for asking.  If I were more experienced I would have tested it my self.  Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var firstChar = dr["Value"].ToString()[0];
var ok = firstChar == 'y' || firstChar = 'Y';
```

and make some performance-tests - but I don't think that this will really be a issue at all.

PS: assuming that the string is not empty - if this might be an issue make it

```
var value = dr["Value"].ToStrin();
var firstChar = String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? 'n' : value[0];
var ok = firstChar == 'y' || firstChar = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/05/31/string-compare-string-equals-josh-free.aspx) out. In my opinion, since you don't have to consider culture-sensitive comparison Equals should be more efficient than Compare method. However, notice that both Trim and ToUpper methods have a performance cost.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this code in a long loop, the issue is not the string comparison, but the way you access the column in your data reader. Get the column number first and use it in the loop.

```
int valueOrdinal = dr.GetOrdinal("Value");
while (dr.Read()) {
    bool ok = dr.GetString(valueOrdinal).Trim().ToUpper() == "Y";
    ...
}
```

If you have a short loop or no loop at all it does not matter anyway.